# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when ViewController is pushed, but not when it's the app's initial VC

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I have a VC that causes a bad access error about 10% of the time. It's mostly code I haven't written (in obj-c and c++), and imports code I haven't written--all of which I'm certain don't cause the error. When I strip out the code that I *did* add, the error still occurs. It's as if the *same exact* code in my project throws an error, but in the sample project this error never occurs. I made the VC the initial start screen and the error won't occur, but when it's pushed by a navigation controller, the error happens 10% or so of the time.

NSZombies don't help me at all, by the way. I'm totally at a loss for what to do.

Comment: `When I strip out the code that I did add, the error still occurs`  Welcome to the world of C++, where *undefined behavior* occurs when you have corrupted memory or overrun buffers, or some similar error.  The best you can do is to duplicate the error consistently, so that you can get your hands dirty and fix it.  The one thing you **don't** want to do is to add code (that has nothing to do with fixiing the error) so as to make the error "go away" (which it really hasn't gone away).

Comment: I just have no idea where to start. I don't know C++, only Obj-C.

Comment: Perhaps the difference between "Initial screen" and "embedded in a nav controller" is key. Sounds like you're nav controller might be slacking on some responsibilities. It's also curious that your sample project is fine, which might indicate that the nav bar there is more simple. I would check the call backs of the nav controller.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I took it out of the NavControl and presented it via `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`. I'm still getting the same error.